# parallel processing of a queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, message-queue

I'm trying to find a way to process a queue in several threads, dynamically adjusting the number of consumers. Basically the task is very well known: multiple producers create messages and submit them into a queue, multiple consumers process messages from the queue. Now, I thought about different ways of doing it utilizing diffrent components like System.Collections.Queue.Synchronized, System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue and System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection but I just can't decide how to do it properly with maximum efficiency so I will be glad to receive some bright ideas through your input.
Here are more details:

- The message rate is expected to be realy intensive in some occasions, but the handling is going to be relatively straight-forward;
- I have no idea how many consumers should I have;
- I want the process to adjust the number of current consumers, instead of having them blocked, depending on the amount of messages enqueued(meaning that I want to populate additional consumer f.e. for each hundred of messages, and on of the consumers should halt if number of enqueued messages is 50 less than the number that was needed to populate it, f.e. third consumer will be populated when the amount of messages has grown over 300, and it should halt when it drops to 250).

This is the idea. Now, I thought about wraping the ConcurrentQueue into a class that will encapsulate the Enqueue method and will check the number of messages after the enqueuing and will make the decision about starting an additional consumer. And the consumer should have within the loop a check that should make a decision about halting it. I think that you will suggest some more interesting solutions.

By the way, one of the situations I still don't know how to handle is theoretically when a last message is being enqueued and in the same time the last consumer has halted. Another situation is also about halting - several consumers will be halted if they will get to the halt check in the same time. How should I deal with these situations?

To demonstrate what do I mean, consider this sample:

```
class MessageController
{
    private BlockingCollection<IMessage> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<IMessage>();

    int amountOfConsumers;

    public void Enqueue(IMessage message)
    {
        messageQueue.Add(message); // point two

        if (Math.Floor((double)messageQueue.Count / 100)+1 > amountOfConsumers) // point three
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                IMessage msg;
                while ((messageQueue.Count > 0) && (Math.Floor((double)((messageQueue.Count + 50) / 100)) + 1 >= amountOfConsumers)) //point one
                {
                    msg = messageQueue.Take();
                    //process msg...
                }

                ConsumerQuit(); // point four
            });

            Interlocked.Increment(ref amountOfConsumers);
        }
    }

    public void ConsumerQuit()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref amountOfConsumers);
    }
}
```

So now when I can point to the specific code lines these are the questions:

- When the last consumer found that there're no messages enqueued(@point one) and before it calls the ConsumerQuit method, the last message arrives and enqueued, then the check for additional consumers is done, and it turns out(@point three) that there is still a consumer working, and because of that one consumer for single message is more than enough - nothing happens, then the ConsumerQuit is finally called, and I have a message stuck in queue.

> ```
> ConsumerTask                       | LastMessageThread
> ------------------------------------------------------
> @point one(messageQueue.Count=0)   | @point two
> no time                            | @point three(amountOfConsumers=1)
> @point four                        | ended;
> ended;                             | ended;
> ```

- Several consumers got to the "point one" check simultaneously when one of them should be halted(f.e. messageQueue.Count is 249), several of them will halt because before the ConsumerQuit will be called on one of them several others will do this check also.

> ```
> ConsumerTask1                  | ConsumerTask2| ConsumerTask3 | ConsumerTask4|
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> @point one(.Count=249;amount=4)| no time      | no time       | @point one   |
> no time                        | @point one   | processing msg| @point four  |
> @point four                    | no time      | @point one    | ended;       |
> ended;                         | @point four  | processing msg| ended;       |
> ended;                         | ended;       | ...           | ended;       |
> ```
>
> Here, in case when the last message is already enqueued, we have one consumer task left that has to handle 249 messages alone, however the worst case can be if all them will halt, after the last message, potentialy hundreds of messages will stuck.

Comment: Use kernel synchro - BlockingCollection etc.  Call back if the performance is inadequate.

Comment: Your problem can be solved by using the `ThreadPool` class and tuning the minimum and maximum number of threads. See [this MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that threads in `ThreadPool` are short-lived, otherwise what would be the meaning of the minimum number of threads? Since the threads are meant to run well defined tasks, the threads are probably just put to sleep when there's nothing to do.

Comment: @didierc Thought about it, but had no one to ask, and this requires sending messages one after the other for processing by some thread that will be constantly running, wanted to prevent this. Also I'm not sure about how big is the overhead when you keep firing short-life threads. Do you know or can you estimate?

Comment: Also, growing the number of running threads in proportion of the number of incoming messages will not get them processed faster. After crossing the maximum number of physical cores available to your process, the performances will start degrading, since the thread management system will start eating more and more CPU power to do its job. However, if you know you'll never reach that maximum, then you won't have that problem, but I doubt that you'll get much better performance that the `ThreadPool` class.

Comment: Aren't your threads constantly running as long as there are tasks to process? Sorry I cannot provide an estimate, perhaps you could make that a SO question?

Comment: @didierc The minimum number of threads defines idle threads which are maintained by the thread pool in order to reduce the time required to satisfy requests for thread pool threads. They are short-lived because they don't have much to do, the only mission is to somehow analyze the message and forward it.

Comment: Well, we don't know that for sure. Perhaps their implementation is to do what you do explicitely with your message queue, ie. check if there's a new task in the queue.  That also would be a good SO question (unless it has already been asked).

Comment: May be I just don't get your idea. To utilize the ThreadPool I have to manualy queue user work items, which requires me to attach also a message to be processed. If so, the thread won't last more than the time required to process a single message. Sorry, but what is SO?

Comment: StackOverflow! This very website! And if this place is not well suited, you could try programmers.stackexchange.com or any other stackexchange.com site which could fit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I've finally came up with a solution, not sure about the performance though. Please consider the following code, any feedback will be much appreciated! I still hope to see some other solutions or ideas, even if they will be absolutely different and will require major changes in approach. This is the objective: "a way to process a queue in several threads, dynamically adjusting the number of consumers"

```
class MessageController
{
    private BlockingCollection<IMessage> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<IMessage>();

    private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    private int amountOfConsumers;

    object o = new object();

    public void Enqueue(IMessage message)
    {
        messageQueue.Add(message);

        mre.WaitOne();
        if (Math.Floor((double)messageQueue.Count / 100)+1 > amountOfConsumers)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref amountOfConsumers);

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                IMessage msg;
                bool repeat = true;

                while (repeat)
                {
                    while ((messageQueue.Count > 0) && (Math.Floor((double)((messageQueue.Count + 50) / 100)) + 1 >= amountOfConsumers))
                    {
                        msg = messageQueue.Take();
                        //process msg...
                    }

                    lock (o)
                    {
                        mre.Reset();

                        if ((messageQueue.Count == 0) || (Math.Ceiling((double)((messageQueue.Count + 51) / 100)) < amountOfConsumers))
                        {
                            ConsumerQuit();
                            repeat = false;
                        }

                        mre.Set();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void ConsumerQuit()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref amountOfConsumers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem you really want to solve, but as long as you have your solution it's great. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: More than happy to share. Well this answer mainly addresses the last part of the question-post(where I addressed the exact lines of code). But still I don't know if this is going to give good performance. And I hope to receive some insight from others.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thoughts are that you are designing this backwards.

When looking at parallelism, you may not always gain efficiency by adding more threads to a single task. sometimes the best number is equal to or less than the number of cores on the machine that you are using. The reason for this is that you are creating more overhead with lock contention and thread switching.

By adding more consumers you may find that the consumption rate actually decreases instead of increases.

One thing to consider is how long does it take to process a message? If this time is significantly longer than the time that it takes to produce a task,why not have a single consumer that simply creates a new Task to process each message?

```
class MessageController
{
    private BlockingCollection<IMessage> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<IMessage>();

    public void Enqueue(IMessage message)
    {
        messageQueue.Add(message);
    }

    public void Consume()
    {
        //This loop will not exit until messageQueue.CompleteAdding() is called
        foreach (var item in messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            IMessage message = item;
            Task.Run(() => ProcessMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The message will be processed relatively fast, it will be somehow analyzed and given away. To create new task with each message is an interesting approach, but as I said the message rate is expected to be realy intensive, and I don't think that it's a good idea to have thousand of tasks running, and hey, haven't you said that the best number is equal or less than the number of cores?:)

Comment: It can be efficient to have thousands of tasks. It is just that you do not always want many tasks doing the same thing. For example processing message does a different task because each message is different so the act of processing it is different. Where having thousands of tasks all trying to consume the same collection may not give a benefit over having just a couple process the task.

Comment: I would suggest trying the following with, and without creating a new task for each message. You may find that this is more than adequate to meet your needs.

Comment: I didn't want to use this approach from the beginning because I'm not sure about if you have big amount of producers, will this only one handle the throughput?